# Migrate project from Mac to Windows - Error: Source file 'Resources\drawable\icon_about.png' could not be found

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

When I migrate project from Mac to Windows I receive many same errors:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Source file 'Resources\drawable\icon_about.png' could not be found. pizhevsoft.Android  C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\pizhevsoft v3\pizhevsoft v3\pizhevsoft\pizhevsoft\pizhevsoft.Android\Resources\drawable\icon_about.png
```

My icons displaying with [X] icon and I don't know how to include in the project ?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: did those files get copied?  If not, copy them to the correct folders and reload the project in VS.  Or manually re-add them to appropriate folders in VS.

Comment: I just archive the project folder with *.zip extension on mac and unarchive the project on windows.

Comment: I didn't know that when I migrate a project the resource directory was left blank, I don't know why this happens, but I just didn't notice that all the files were missing.

Comment: @RositsaV Could you open the icon? If no, I guess the migration would lose something. Could you copy a new one to recheck?

Comment: "I just archive the project folder with *.zip" haha what? Have you heard of version control? Even on the smallest projects, create a repository of some sort.